# jquery drill down

Tags: jquery

I am trying to change the class of a button when a checkbox is checked but I'm having trouble getting it right. When the checkbox is selected I want to change the buttons class to buttonsshow from buttonshide.

HTML

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <input id="ChartstoDisplayAll" type="checkbox"     name="ctl00$MainContent$ChartstoDisplayAll" /><label for="ChartstoDisplayAll">Select All</label>
    <p class="checkbox" style="margin-left:5px;"> or select individually below </p>
    <hr class="horizline" style="width:870px;"/>
</div>

    <div id="buttons" class="buttonshide">
        <input type="image" name="ctl00$MainContent$btnGetChart"  id="MainContent_btnGetChart" title="Click here to retrieve the charts" Text="Build the  Charts" src="Styles/Images/stats.png" alt="Build the Charts" align="left" />
        <p style="font-size:.8em; font-weight:bold;">Build Charts</p>
    </div>
```

FYI...There is other html between these two divs. I took it out for brevity as none have an id of buttons.

Here is the javascript. (the latest way that I've tried)

```
 //this script will change the style of the "Select All" checkbox and make visible the "Build Chart" button
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#ChartstoDisplayAll').click(
          function () {
              $("INPUT[type='checkbox']").attr('checked', $('#ChartstoDisplayAll').is(':checked'));
              $(this).next().toggleClass("selected");
              $(this).find("buttons").toggleclass("buttonsshow");
          });
  });
```

​
Here is the fiddle link
http://jsfiddle.net/dinotom/h25tM/2/

Here is the completed, working script which changes the text color and shows the button when the checkbox is selected.

```
 //this script will change the style of the "Select All" checkbox and make visible the "Build Chart" button
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#ChartstoDisplayAll').change(
          function () {
              if ($('#ChartstoDisplayAll').is(':checked')) {
                  $(this).next().addClass("selected");
                  $('#buttons').addClass("buttonsshow").removeClass('buttonshide');
              } else {
                  $('#buttons').addClass("buttonshide").removeClass('buttonsshow');
                  $(this).next().removeClass("selected");
              }
          });
  });
```

Comment: You've clearly expplained what you want, and that's awesome. But what errors are you getting? What is the behavior you're seeing? Tell us what this is doing. Give us a place to start.

Comment: What should be the class `selected` you are trying to add?

Comment: The .selected is for the checkbox text color and that works properly as you see in the fiddle, but i need to drill down to the button and change its class also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if ($('#ChartstoDisplayAll').is(':checked')) {
  $(this).find("buttons").addClass("buttonsshow").removeClass('buttonshide');
} else {
  $(this).find("buttons").addClass("buttonshide").removeClass('buttonsshow');
}
```

Also, you should use the [change](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event instead of [click](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

Comment: That should be in your function instead of $(this).find("buttons").toggleclass("buttonsshow");

Comment: The only error in my script is this line...$(this).find("buttons").toggleclass("buttonsshow"); It is clearly not finding the right object to change class for

Comment: I changed that line to your code, both in the fiddle and on my page and it doesnt change the buttons class.

Comment: jmort253...It's simple, the first part of the script changes the class to selected, which changes the text color of the checkbox to green. That works, this doesn't.I also want an invisible button to display when that checkbox is checked. That is done through the two css selectors buttonsshow and buttonshide.

Answer (score 0):

Basically this should help:

### *[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vVqhW/1/)*

```
$('#ChartstoDisplayAll').on('change', function() {
    $(this).next('label').toggleClass("selected");      
    $("input[type='image']").toggleClass("buttonsshow");      
});
```

BTW: I changed your CSS and added some comments, take a look in the demo